# el-get failed to load package

Tags: emacs, elisp, el-get

I installed [`help-fns+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/help-fns%2b.el) with el-get, but I can't find the functions with `M-x`.
I have to explicitly add
`(require 'help-fns+)`
in my init file. Is this a issue with el-get or `help-fns+.el`?

Here's my setting in the init file for el-get.

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/el-get/el-get")
(unless (require 'el-get nil 'noerror)
(with-current-buffer
(url-retrieve-synchronously
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dimitri/el-get/master/el-get-install.el")
(goto-char (point-max))
(eval-print-last-sexp)))
(add-to-list 'el-get-recipe-path "~/.emacs.d/el-get-user/recipes")
(el-get 'sync)
```

Comment: But even if it is not requried, it should be autoloaded once I run its commands. It's probably not wise to use el-get any more. I am switching to the official packages.el. Thank you all the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in the code you show tells Emacs to load [`help-fns+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/help-fns%2b.el) - except the explicit `(require 'help-fns+)`.  Except, that is, if you have something in `recipes` that takes care of this.  Show all of the relevant code and perhaps someone can help more with it.

Otherwise, yes, to load `help-fns+.el` you need to tell Emacs to load it!  And one way to do that is to (1) put that library in your `load-path` and then (2) `(require 'help-fns+)`.